# Security and Global variable

Tags: asp.net

Is there any security risks to using a global variable (singleton) initialized in the global.asax file. I plan on storing app settings like connection strings in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't expose it with any interface there is no security risk in having anything in memory as far as I know. However, consider using ConfigurationManager for the purpose of accessing and managing the configuration ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, not in itself. The `global.asa` file is protected by IIS, so that you can for example not browse to it to try to get it to reveal any information.

The only risk is if you have code anywhere that reads from the variable and does something like put it on a page or store it in a cookie.

If this is for ASP.NET, it the `global.asax` file that you use instead. You can also use the `web.config` file to store some information, then it's editable without having to recompile the application.

Comment: If I have a class that is used as a singleton with settings, and access it via my own code is there any security risk?

Comment: @chobo: There is no security risk from the object itself. The only way that the information can be exposed is if you have code somewhere that reads information from the object and uses it in an unsafe way.